# How to update a part of a timestamp field in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, timestamp

Example: My timestamp: 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 in table temp and field temp_date.
I want to update 2018 to 2016 by SQL. How can I ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
UPDATE temp
SET temp_date = temp_date - interval '2 years'
WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM temp_date) = 2018;
```

If you want to set it to an exact year, e.g. if your `WHERE` clause uses something other than the year, or if you're not using a `WHERE` clause at all:

```
UPDATE temp
SET temp_date = temp_date +
    (2016 - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM temp_date) || ' years')::interval
WHERE foo = 'bar';
```

For more details, refer to [the mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4199e4a414eb3dd2e9a25896f0693be6@biglumber.com).

Comment: How can if we wanna adding some years ?

Comment: I'd imagine, UPDATE temp
SET temp_date = temp_date + interval '2 years'
WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM temp_date) = 2018;

Comment: You can use an `interval` to add or subtract any amount of time from a `timestamp` value, even like `interval '2 years 5 months -1 day 12 hours 4 seconds'`.

Comment: sorry because I been tried + interval but my data was updated to NULL. So i think has something wrong !

Comment: I think I forgot something, I try again and it work, thanks @Patrick

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
UPDATE temp
   SET temp_date = temp_date - (date_trunc('year', temp_date ) - date '2016-1-1')
```

The above update assigns '2016' to all dates in the table, 
leaving remaining date parts (month-day-hour etc.) unchanged

Comment: This does not address the question. Besides, you update _all_ rows, even those where the year is already 2016, and that is _very_ inefficient on a large table. And what about `temp_date`s in 2014?

Comment: @Patrick, you are absolutely right, this is very very very inefficient. But everyone can very easily solve this problem using simple `WHERE` condition. Regarding `2014` - it also is "replaced" with 2016, please play with this query and you will see.

Comment: If there is a simple solution already, then why add an inefficient one which has side effects not asked for?

Comment: @Patrick you citicise others and blame them for unefficiency, but you can't see in your own answer that your `WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM temp_date) = 2018;` is unable to use an index and always must do a full table scan.

Comment: The question is about updating a number of rows, not something that would conceivably happen very often so an index would probably mean more overhead (in building and maintaining) than benefit in this case. Other than that, an index can be built on the expression. But index issues aside, it is far better to have a solution that actually works than one that very slowly does the wrong thing. Your solution would not use an index either because it has to update **all** rows, in the process making the table twice as big as before.